# I don't understand how to fix the error with a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

There is not enough space for the list, it seems that I did this before and everything worked fine, but now it doesn’t. I recently started developing on flutter, so I might have missed something, I would be grateful if you can help with this error.

**home_screen**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final todoRepository = TodoRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocProvider<TodoBloc>(
      create: (context) => TodoBloc(todoRepository),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Flutter Todos'),
          ),
          // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          //   onPressed: () {
          //     // _addTodo(context);
          //     final newTodo = Todo(description: 'Todo 1');
          //     BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(CreateTodos(newTodo));
          //   },
          //   child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          // ),
          body: Column(
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ActionButton(),
              TodoList(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

**list_screen**

```
class TodoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Todo todo;
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      // final todos = (state is TodoLoadedState);
      // return Container();

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                // return _buildListTile(state.loadedUser[index]);
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        child: ListTile(
                            title: Column(children: [
                  Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}')
                ])))));
      }
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Expanded must be in a Column or a Row. And Don't use a Container without parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your HomePage widget code like so:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final todoRepository = TodoRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocProvider<TodoBloc>(
      create: (context) => TodoBloc(todoRepository),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Flutter Todos'),
          ),
          // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          //   onPressed: () {
          //     // _addTodo(context);
          //     final newTodo = Todo(description: 'Todo 1');
          //     BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(CreateTodos(newTodo));
          //   },
          //   child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          // ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ActionButton(),
                TodoList(),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

And Add this line

```dart
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

to your `ListView.builder()` widget in your `TodoList` widget

---

Explanation:
When your content of your screen exceeds its height, you need to wrap it with a scrollable widget (like `SingleChildScrollView`) to allow scrolling to access the remaining content.
However, if you have another scrollable widget inside your parent scrollable widget (Your `ListView` in your `TodoList` widget, then the scrolling will have conflict. So that's why you can add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the child scrollable to allow scrolling of the parent scrollable only.

---

Update:

For the error `Exception caught by widgets library Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget` it's happening because you have an `Expanded` widget as a direct child of your `ListView` widget in your `TodoList` widget. So removing the `Expanded` widget will fix the error

[image]

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Column(
        children: [
          Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Note: I kept your `Container` widget just in case you put it for a reason to add more styling to your ListTile, but I recommend you remove it if you're not going to do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped.

Now I have the following error in the console, 1 item in the list = 1 error in the console:

Exception caught by widgets library 
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. 

Do not prompt, in what it can be the reason?
The app itself starts up and runs fine.

Comment: You're very welcome. :D See my updated answer for a fix of the last error.

Comment: Thank you again so much!

Comment: You're welcome again :) Feel free to accept the answer if your problem was resolved. Or let me know if another error happenned

Comment: Okey :) I have one more problem, I tried all the options that I knew, but it did not help) 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70687508/10830211

Comment: This is another question. And I'm happy to help with it. But it would be more appropriate of you if you accept my answer on this issue since it was solved before asking for help in a separate question

Comment: Ahhh I got it. Now I understand. I just didn't know there was such a function as accepting an answer. Now I'll know)

Answer (score 0):

You can try SingleChildScrollView Widget to overcome on Overflow issue.

And

Wrap Expanded widget with Column or Row Widget.

like-

```
   Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: Text("")),
                ],
              )
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Now I have the following error in the console, 1 item in the list = 1 error in the console: Exception caught by widgets library Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
 Do not prompt, in what it can be the reason?
The app itself starts up and runs fine.